# Gearing down a PF XL

Tags: building, power-functions, gears

I'm looking for the best way to gear down a Power Function XL.

I need to achieve a very slow output RPM (less than 1-2 RPM). I've tried a 625:1 gear (trough 40:8 gear). Can someone link to a well done gearbox like that? Moreover, how I can make an axle more resistant at high torque (I've tried with brick round 2x2).

Comment: Do you mean less than 1-2 RPM?  As written, you're indicating greater than 1-2 RPM.

Comment: Yeah, I mean <1-2RPM (or around).

Answer (score 4):

The XL motor runs at approximately 220 RPM.  Therefore, the following gearbox from the [ELEC 201 class LEGO Design module from Rice](https://www.clear.rice.edu/elec201/Book/legos.html) should be sufficient:

[image: LEGO 243:1 Gearbox]

Answer (score 2):

You can use a worm gear for a compact, high ratio gearbox. By putting a worm gear on the motor shaft and using it to drive a 24 tooth gear you can achieve a 24:1 reduction.

[image: For example]

For high torque applications you could use multiple parallel axles held together by gears or wheel hubs.

Comment: Sadly, a 24:1 doesn't resolve my problem. Maybe i can add some other gear using worm gear as the input.

Comment: Then by using two of these assemblies you can achieve 576:1 reduction. Or if that is too much, you can get another gear either before or after this setup for an additional 2:1 or 3:1 reduction.